# Able to access url even after closing IDE

Tags: python, flask

Developing a simple application in Flask. I am able to access my URL even after I close the IDE(PyCharm). Also, I think because my previous code is continuously running on the port, my latest code changes are not being reflected.
My host is 0.0.0.0 and port is 5000.

```
from cs50.sql import SQL
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQL("sqlite:///test.db")

@app.route("/login", methods = ["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register", methods = ["POST"])
def register():
    if request.form["name"] == "" or request.form["dorm"] == "":
        return render_template("failure.html")
    rows = db.execute("INSERT INTO students (name, dorm) VALUES(:name, :dorm)", name = request.form["name"], dorm = request.form["dorm"])
    return render_template("success.html", registrant = rows)

@app.route("/all", methods = ["GET"])
def seeAllUsers():
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM students")
    return render_template("all_users.html", rows = rows)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

localhost:5000/login is always online. Other 'GET' URLs are not.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is probably not closing the running program when you exit it. Use the task manager or `ps -A` if you are on Linux or macOS to see the running programs. You will probably see a `python ...` application still running.

Comment: Task manager doesn't show a python program running. Also, while exiting PyCharm asks me if I wan't to disconnect/terminate the ongoing process. I did terminate it before close it. Could it be that it continues to run because I'm running it publicly (host = 0.0.0.0) and hence server continues to run even after IDE is closed?

Comment: Then maybe your browser is only displaying the cached version of the page. Try if it is also accessible from another browser.

Comment: I did think of that, and tried using incognito. Was still able to access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my issue was that I was running publicly (host = 0.0.0.0). As soon as I removed explicitly mentioning the host, it started to work fine using

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```